# Run servlet as homepage

Tags: servlets, url-routing, html

I have a dynamic web project with a servlet (structure below).

When right-clicking **HomeServlet.java --> Run as --> Run on Server --> Tomcat...**

It runs fine with the URL: http://localhost:8080/JSTLTest/HomeServlet

When right-clicking **JSTLTest --> Run as --> Run on Server --> Tomcat...**

I get an error and this URL is used: http://localhost:8080/JSTLTest/

The problem is, i want to deploy it on a server like AWS elastic beanstalk and i guess it doesn't work because he won't use the servlet to start, like:
http://default-environment-9a5exxxd3z.elasticbeanstalk.com/**HomeServlet**

Is my web.xml wrong?

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">
    <display-name>JSTLTest</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Home</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.journaldev.servlet.HomeServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Home</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/HomeServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Structure:

[image]

Comment: didn't understand the question very well. do you want HomeServlet to run at the start of tomcat? then add `<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>` to the servlet in web.xml. it will run the `init()` method on tomcat startup

Comment: tried that already tomcat still uses http://localhost:8080/JSTLTest/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
<url-pattern>/HomeServlet</url-pattern>
```

with

```
<url-pattern></url-pattern>
```

The url pattern is the url that added to the the protocol + server + port + context (something like http://localhost:8080/myapp) can be used to access to a particular servlet.

Note the pattern must be **empty**. The pattern **/** is the default pattern. So it match all possible patterns (also what you don't like).

Comment: ah great that did it! Thank you! Will accept it as answer in 6 minutes ^^